# inconsistent non-exhaustive pattern matching with if statements

Tags: algorithm, rust, pattern-matching

I've wrote two equivalent functions in Rust, one compiles the other doesn't.

Program 1:

```rust
pub fn majority_element<T: Eq>(nums: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    nums.iter().fold(None, |acc, curr| {
        match acc {
            None => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((0, prev)) if prev != curr => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((count, prev)) => Some((count + if prev == curr { 1 } else { -1 }, prev)),
        }
    }).map(|(_, val)| val)
}
```

program 2 (doesn't compile)

```rust
pub fn majority_element<T: Eq>(nums: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    nums.iter().fold(None, |acc, curr| {
        match acc {
            None => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((0, prev)) if prev != curr => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((count, prev)) if prev == curr => Some((count + 1, prev)),
            Some((count, prev)) if prev != curr => Some((count - 1, prev)),
        }
    }).map(|(_, val)| val)
}
```

```
error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Some(_)` not covered
 --> src/lib.rs:3:15
  |
3 |         match acc {
  |               ^^^ pattern `Some(_)` not covered
  |
```

I prefer the second one because it expresses more clearly my intent.

Is this a compiler quirk or my pattern is actually not exhaustive? (and if so what am I missing?)
The type of acc is: `Option<(usize, &T)>`

Comment: One way to make the second version compile is adding `_ => unreachable!(),` as the final match arm.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't understand that either `x == y` or `x != y`, but for generic types this also can be false. I can create a type that returns `false` for both `a == b` and `a != b` fairly easily:

```rust
struct Evil;

impl PartialEq for Evil {
    fn eq(&self, _other: &Self) -> bool { false }
    fn ne(&self, _other: &Self) -> bool { false }
}

impl Eq for Evil {}

#[test]
fn test() {
    assert!(!(Evil == Evil));
    assert!(!(Evil != Evil));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72347a1aecec07d69ba5ffb9548cd823).

Such implementation violates the contract of `PartialEq`, [as it requires that](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html):

> `a != b` if and only if `!(a == b)`.

But it is still possible to write without unsafe code. That means that we can for example panic if this contract is violated, but we cannot cause undefined behavior. Unfortunately, non-exhaustive match can cause UB, and such is your case: if none of the arms matches you don't return any value from the function.

So the compiler not only does not, but also cannot rely on that. If you prefer, you can rewrite the code in the following way:

```rust
pub fn majority_element2<T: Eq>(nums: &[T]) -> Option<&T> {
    nums.iter()
        .fold(None, |acc, curr| match acc {
            None => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((0, prev)) if prev != curr => Some((1, curr)),
            Some((count, prev)) => match prev == curr {
                true => Some((count + 1, prev)),
                false => Some((count - 1, prev)),
            },
        })
        .map(|(_, val)| val)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! unrelated question:
Can you merge the first two patterns in the pattern matching? (None and Some((0, ... )

Comment: @IsmailMaj no, a pattern can not summon values out of nowhere, and the pattern guard applies after the entire pattern.

Comment: FWIW as an alternative to to Chayim's version you could just use the pattern *without* a guard for the final alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I knew. Also, I was mostly wondering if you could apply a pattern guard to only a subset. Looks like you can't.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant whether the compiler is able to assume that `!(x == y)` implies `x != y`. The compiler simply assumes that all guard expressions can fail – even `if true`. The reasoning is that you could simply omit a guard if you are sure it always applies.

Comment: Seems like @SvenMarnach is right, even `_ if true` doesn't work

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sure, maybe I overlooked that, but I wanted to answer "is this a compiler quirk or my pattern is not exhaustive".